# Parse.Query.each() not including all records

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've seeing a bug in the latest Parse javascript SDK (v 1.4.2) that
Parse.Query.each() doesn't seem to go though all the matching records. It seems have stopped after certain point.

I have a UserLocation class that stores user location GeoPoints (in column "geo"). I'm trying to find the list of user locations whose distance to a venue location is less than 10 miles. As I understand that Parse.Query.find() has a limit of 1000. According to this post, Parse.Query.each() doesn't have such limit:
https://parse.com/questions/pfquery-setskip-does-not-skip-beyond-10000

But that doesn't seem to be the case judging from my test results:

```
mylocation.get("deviceId")
"fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4"
venueGeo.milesTo(mylocation.get("geo"));
2.1965871191375173
```

As you see, my location is about 2 miles from the venue location. But if I run the distance query of 10 miles, the result doesn’t have my location:

```
var locationQuery = new Parse.Query("UserLocation").withinMiles("geo", venueGeo, 10);
results = [] ;
locationQuery.each(function(location) {results.push(location.get("deviceId"))})
b.Promise {_resolved: false, _rejected: false, _resolvedCallbacks: Array[0], _rejectedCallbacks: Array[0], resolve: function…}
results.length
107
results.indexOf("fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4")
-1
```

But if I add extra constraint to the query to return records whose deviceId is equal to my location’s device it. Parse.Query.each() actually includes it. I’d image the new query would return only subsets of the previous query. But it’s actually returning a record that’s not in the previous query:

```
var locationQuery = new Parse.Query("UserLocation").withinMiles("geo", venueGeo, 10).equalTo("deviceId", "fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4");
results = [] ; 
locationQuery.each(function(location) {results.push(location.get("deviceId"))})
b.Promise {_resolved: false, _rejected: false, _resolvedCallbacks: Array[0], _rejectedCallbacks: Array[0], resolve: function…}
results.length
1
results.indexOf("fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4")
0
```

If I page through the records using Parse.Query.limit(1000) and Parse.Query.skip(), I finally found my record at page 8

```
locationQuery.skip(7000)
locationQuery.find().then(function(locations){
  results = locations.map(function(location){
    return location.get("deviceId");
  })
})
results.indexOf("fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4")
-1

locationQuery.skip(8000)
locationQuery.find().then(function(locations){
  results = locations.map(function(location){
    return location.get("deviceId");
  })
})
results.indexOf("fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4")

927
```

But paging has its own limitation as you can't skip more than 10000 records, not to mention it's less efficient.

This seems to contradict that the Parse javascript Documentation says that Parse.Query.each() doesn't have a limit. Has anybody run into the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in the docs where we're told that each() is not subject to the 1k limit, but it's reasonable that it wouldn't be.  The code posted shows calls and responses that seem to me might be subject to a race condition, that is, the each promise might not be fulfilled at the time results are measured.  Here's a deterministic test that might well find the record:

```
var locationQuery = new Parse.Query("UserLocation");
locationQuery.withinMiles("geo", venueGeo, 10);
results = []; 
locationQuery.each(function(location {
    results.push(location.get("deviceId"));
}).then(function() {
    console.log("results length=" + results.length);
    console.log("index of target device id=" + results.indexOf("fa72f38bc0af44f090824a38fd1963b4"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was under the impression that Parse.Query.each() doesn't impose an upper bound by reading this [post](https://parse.com/questions/paging-through-more-than-10000-results)
"Parse.Query.each() which will let you fetch every object that matches the query with no upper bounds."

The code I pasted above is from Chrome javascript console. In my real node.js code, I do have the "then" block flowing "each":

`return locationQuery.each(function(location){
    filteredLocations.push(location);
}).then(function(){
    return filteredLocations;
});`

Comment: Hmm.  Hector gives so many good answers, so I guess it is an undocumented feature that forEach has no upper bound.  Given that (and that you're running your queries sequentially), it sure seems like you have found a legit bug.  I'll bet they'd appreciate if you reported it....  One work-around would be running the query with `find()` with paging via `skip()`.  Should I edit my answer to illustrate, or do you know how to do that?

Comment: I did file a bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/103854869948544/

It looks like the problem only happens when the query involves GeoPoint.

Skip has its own limit (can't skip for more than 10000). So that doesn't work for me either. I did try Hector's suggestion of using orderBy + limit + skip. That's not working for me either (at least not yet, still debugging). Initial impression is that orderBy is applied after retrieving the records, not prior to applying the constraints so using the orderBy result as the delimiter for next batch didn't work.